# DisplayErrorMessage in Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

How can I use displayErrorMessage
In API They defiend but I can't use that method.
I need your help.....

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var that = this;
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        alert(element.nodeName);
        if(element.nodeName == 'LABEL'){
            displayErrorMessage('LABEL');
            displayErrorMessage("LABEL");
        } else if( element.nodeName == 'INPUT'){
            displayErrorMessage('INPUT');
            displayErrorMessage("INPUT");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would code it as:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.displayErrorMessage('LABEL');
```

However, displayErrorMessage is no different than alert and it doesn't work at all in JFE.  So, you are better off just using alert.